# Embed threaded WindowsFormsHost in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF application and an ActiveX control that gets embedded into the WPF application using a `WindowsFormsHost` control.
The `ActiveX` control is used to communicate with an external application that draws 3D contents into the control.

One big issue of this setup is that if the ActiveX control does some long running operations, the rest of the WPF application gets blocked.
I would like to solve this issue and somehow prevent the `ActiveX` control to be hosted on the same thread as the remaining controls in my UI.

I searched for possible solutions and found this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dwayneneed/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual/

Unfortunately I cannot use this sample to host a `WindowsFormsHost` element as it is not derived from `Visual`.
The only other option I could implement so far is to host the `ActiveX` control inside a separate window which I launch on a separate thread.
Although this works it is quite messy to manage as I have to manually snap the separate window to the main window to get kind of a uniform layout.

Is there anything else I can try to achieve a single-window experience but also having the `ActiveX` control hosted on a separate thread?

Comment: Unless the ActiveX is marked as multi-thread-safe, which is unlikely (we're talking UI here), you are stuck with it being on the UI thread

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. At least I can achieve a single-window like experience by removing all styles and borders from the windows and implement them on my own. Better than my first attempt with two windows.